# detected problems with app native libraries libutility.so : text relocations

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, camera, edit

Hi everyone I try to use this project [enter link description here](https://github.com/Zhaoss/WeiXinRecordedDemo) for my App  , its a custom camera for  record video and edit it with ffmepg . [Preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfw2m.png) ,  [Second preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhiCg.png) 
The problem is when I try to use it on my app I got this error **libutility.so : text relocations** , I make some research and I find the problem it looks like I can usethis project with a TargetSdk Higher than 22 . So  I would like to know if someone here have a solution different than downgrade my app to 22  or if someone know a better custom camera who can edit video just as this one  on android  , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

i experienced the same issue.
This how to resolve it.

1) you either downgrade your target SDK to 22 OR
you do a global search of the warning message, trace it to the the library that giving the error and edit the line of the code. Then the issue will be resolved.
Happy coding